# Will sound be generated by the capture of air from a vacume?

Tags: kinematics, acoustics, vacuum

I have a thought experiment. If I had a box sized vacuum sitting on the floor in front of me and I were to instantaneously remove all the walls of my box. Would the capturing of air from that vacuum make a noticeable sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Once the walls are magically removed, the air surrounding the box will suddenly rush inwards toward the center of the box volume- thereby propagating a rarefaction wave outwards at the speed of sound- which you will hear. Very soon thereafter, all the inrushing air will meet at the center of the box volume and rebound, propagating a compression wave outwards.

You would therefore hear something like a "KA-POP" noise.

Comment: Awesome, okay great thanks for clearing that up for me!